# Looking for a replacement part; need help finding from photo

Tags: transistors, amplifier, replacement

[image: Fender Chorus Guitar Amp Blown Part]

I blew out a part in my dad's Fender Chorus guitar amplifier several years ago. I didn't ever get around to fixing it for him, no clue why, but I really should.

Problem is I can't find this part or an equivalent replacement anywhere.

So I'm turning to you guys. Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Also make sure you know the correct assembly process with silicone grease, mica washer, insulating washer under the screw. If it's not thermally coupled to the heatsink but electrically isolated, it'll just pop again.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of schematics for Fender amps online, I found this as a likely [candidate](https://bmamps.com/Schematics/fender/Ultimate_Chorus_Service_Manual.pdf).

The device is likely a TIP142 with the "TI" burned off.

Add: Since that's the device you need to heed some warnings in trying to repair the amp.

1. The TIP142/147 are Darlington pairs and in this amplifier are operated in Class A-B. This means they get quite warm with no output (they typically dissipate about 2-3 W at idle).
2. Check the diodes CR42-CR45. If one of these is open (or a bad soldered joint) you will blow your replacement device.
3. If you have EE skills I'd suggest that you break the op amp output signal from the final stage and check the op amp is ok. If you don't understand what I just said, then replace the MC1436 as well as the TIP142.

Comment: I see it... yeah, I'm pretty sure you're right. The amp is a Fender Chorus, as you have discovered. That's exactly the amp, so yeah, I'm gonna say a TIP142 as well

Comment: 1971 week 8 , good catch @Jack

Comment: Glad I checked back. Thanks for the added info. I actually am an electromechanical engineer. This project was a long time ago. And I never could find the right part. Now I have. So I'll get replacements for that entire line just to be safe. I'd rather have them and need them then need them and be screwed. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Logo is Motorola.

The type should say "D718" for a "2SD718" transistor. But is says "DE718", I'm not sure what the extra "E" means.
The 2SD718 is a high power NPN transistor. 120V, 8A, 80W with a gain of about 100.

[ADDED] I agree with @JackCreasey, it is most likely the Motorola TIP142 darlington transistor.

Comment: That makes sense, sounds appropriate. Are they still in production?

Comment: Search for them or look for an appropriate replacement type matching the specs. Double check the part type by analyzing the circuitry around that said transistor to be sure.

Comment: When you know the exact type of the amplifier, you might find the schematics online. Keep in mind that the transistor might not be the original one, but it might already have been replaced with another type.

The transistor blown might be result of something else. Someone (with the schematic) can probably check that with only a multimeter.

Comment: I was replacing a totally other part downstream. And this amp is old. So I think the extra heat just gave the transistor enough to blow. It started smoking and just popped

Comment: Jack Creasey below found the amp schematic, exact amp, and discovered it's a TIP142. And I see it on the blown transistor. So I'm pretty sure his answer is right. But thank you guys!!!